# Viewpage and fragments

Tags: android

When I slide or click on the TAB, always call the next option card method. Each page is a fragment, how can I call in advance if it is not to the next page fragments in the way?

Comment: Could you upload the image and describe it?

Answer (score 0):

Use `ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(k)` to cache fragments of ViewPager from n-k to n+k